# Why is my kitchen water supply so high?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I'm about to move into a new apartment in Germany, which in most cases you need to put in your own kitchen!

One confusing thing about the apartment I've rented is that the water supply (outlet?) is above where the kitchen counter would be. Any ideas why this would be and solutions for dealing with it?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. An idea of how high each of these pipes is would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There are faucets not part of the desk but mounted directly onto the wall.
Some of these faucet-things have a heater unit above the tap. As there is only one outlet instead of two this installation could be designed for this kind of tap.

I don't see marks of a former installation on the tiles that could give a hint of what was installed before you came. So you should ask your landlord what is expected to be there. They surely have advice for you.

I assume you have to provide the kitchen on your own when you move in? Then, if you'd like to have something that has the heater unit below the desk, perhaps you can connect this outlet with your under-desk installation. Ask the experts to suggest something that you like.

Comment: So it appears that this apartment does not have a central hot water system, but must be fitted with point of use water heaters at the kitchen sink and the shower.

Comment: Are you the first occupant of a new or renovated apartment? It is hard to believe that the tenant is required to install kitchen counters, water heater, plumbing, etc. but evidently this is the case in Germany: https://www.howtogermany.com/pages/housing.html

Comment: this is Germany, flats come completely bare and when you move out you need to renovate it back to this state for the next tenant unless they agree to take it over as you have provided it.

Comment: @James Burke, I suppose that in Germany the normal period of occupancy of first rate flats is longer than in the US. Having all the kitchen cabinets removable does allow cleaning and sealing around pipes that is not possible with built-in cabinets. Are there commercial services that install all the basic systems in new flats?

Comment: There are also flats with a built-in kitchen in germany. The landlord of course wants some more rent for that but the tenants don't have to buy kitchen furniture that they probably can't use any more if they move to their next flat.